# Can we develop a service in android which can be called by any other app?

Tags: android, android-service

We can develop Services in an app which can be called by that application itself. It is possible to call that service from any other application without actually running the parent app which contains the service ?

It would be great if some code example is provided.

Comment: can you use content provider

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to start your service like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.xxx.yyy", "com.xxx.yyy.YourService"));
ComponentName c = context.startService(i);
```

You should have following as applicationId :

```
defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.xxx.yyy"
}
```

And you need to define it in manifest as follow :

```
<service android:name="com.xxx.yyy.YourService"
         android:exported="true"/>
```